# Center full screen image vertically

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment, centering

I want to center an full screen image vertically.
I can't define image in CSS because the image depends on URL parameters.

```
<div>
    <img src="photo.jpg">
</div>

div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If I define my image CSS like this:

```
div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

My image will stretch and be deformed in height to fit on screen.

If I define my image CSS like this (just without defining height):

```
div img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

My image will not stretch/be deformed, but it will start at `top: 0` of the image. What I want is the image to be centered vertically and the overflow of it's height to be hidden.

Basically I want the same behaviour I would get in CSS with background centered:

```
background: url(photo.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that CSS `object-fit: cover` works on this but I'm looking for a more cross-browser solution since this property does not work in every browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

EDIT

also its a bad practice to give the image both height and width. this will always override the aspect ratio of the image and stretch it in some direction.

use this for img

```
div img {
    width: 100%;    
}
```

This will first position the division `50%` form top. i.e. the image will now have its topmost part at `50%` of the page height then the translate property will move the image upward by `50%` of its height essentially centering the image

Comment: Thanks Rohit, but it didn't work for me in chrome v49.

Comment: can you please share a screenshot? maybe host it on imgur and paste a link here

Comment: I don't see how this would work. You are moving the div with `translate`, which will move the contents of the div right along with it.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```css
div {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

img { 
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://www.smallbusinesssaturdayuk.com/Images/Small-Business-Saturday-UK-Google-Plus.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, but it does not work. Your image is smaller than the div but if you set the image to `height: 200px;` and `width: 200px` in your example you will see.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow js, you can do this (assuming the image has id 'img'):

```
#img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

A negative margin top needs to be set using js or jQuery (on resize):

```
$('#img').css('margin-top', '-'+($('#img').height()/2)+'px');
```

Comment: You would need to set the top to 50% minus half the height of the image.

Comment: That's exactly what is going on here... :-)

Comment: Thanks @JoostS. With JQuery I can even set background-image and have a simpler solution in CSS with `background-position: center` and `background-size: cover`. But if I get there with no-JS will be better.